# Where to ask questions proposed competition

Tags: discussion

Suppose I have an idea for a competition, but am a little iffy on the details.  Where do I ask questions about what to do for it?

Comment: Is it odd that we have something precisely for this?

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! It's great that you want to contribute. :) As Alex said, you're looking for the sandbox. I've closed your question as a duplicate of our meta FAQ about the sandbox, where you'll find some more details.

Comment: @BaldBantha The fact that we have a sandbox is unusual in the context of the SE network but it works well for us, so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! For that we have the [Sandbox for Proposed Challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1). You post your challenge idea as an answer to that post and the community can provide feedback before the challenge is posted to the main site.